# NetSuite REST API - How to update a sales order as shipped with Tracking Number

Tags: integration, netsuite, endpoint, rest

I am trying to find a way to update a Sales Order as "shipped" back to Netsuite and to add the Tracking Number.
I can't find the best way to do this. I have researched the Sales Order API and the Patch request looks like there is no specific field for a Tracking Number.

PATCH /salesOrder/{id}

Or the best endpoint to use is the Item Fulfillment?

https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2021.1/index.html#tag-itemFulfillment

Any ideas are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you tell  me the exact field names in netsuite that you try to update?

Answer (score 0):

the tracking number field is a derived field -- it is derived from the tracking numbers on any invoices that are linked to the sales order.  To get that field to populate, first create an item fulfillment from the sales order using a transformation and then create an invoice from the sales order, also using a transformation.  If you fill out the tracking number on the invoice, it will also appear in the tracking numbers field on the sales order.